# Syntax for executing a function on a range using CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

Pretty inexperienced with VBA - I'm trying to understand basic syntax here - and I'm generalizing for simplicity's sake.

Given this function intended to accept a SINGLE CELL with a text value of a file path ( Example: "C:\Test\Path" ) and return an array of strings ( Example: {"C","Test","Path"} ) using the Split function with "\" as a delimitator.

*Bare in mind - there is most likely a better way to achieve the desired result here - I'm not interested in that. I'm trying to understand VBA syntax more than anything here.*

```
Function SplitPath(rng As Range) As String()
 Dim arr() As String
 Dim str As String
 str = rng.Cells(1, 1).Value
 arr = Split(str, "\")
 SplitPath = arr
End Function
```

Everything works fine when supplied with a range - such as SplitPath(A1:C1) - in the workbook and pressing enter. Assuming A1 contains a string that is a path - "C:\Test\Path", an array of strings is returned - {"C","Test","Path"} - and adjacent cells are filled with the text values.

It works because the function is hard-coded to pull the first cell's value (1,1) or in our example (A1). Which admittedly feels messy to me, I just don't know how to do it otherwise.

Now for the question - what modifications to this code need to be made in order to allow me to supply a range - such as SplitPath(A1:C1) - then using CRTL-SHIFT-ENTER to have VBA execute the Split on each individual cell in the range, returning an array that contains arrays of strings for each cell. For example if:

```
A1 = "C:\Test\Path"
B1 = "C:\Next\Path"
C1 = "C:\Last\Path"
```

and {SplitPath(A1:C1)} was executed in a cell in the workbook using CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER

the return should be

```
{
 {"C","Test","Path"};
 {"C","Next","Path"};
 {"C","Last","Path"};
}
```

or I guess

```
{
 {"C";"Test";"Path"},
 {"C";"Next";"Path"},
 {"C";"Last";"Path"},
}
```

( to be honest - I don't really understand the difference between arrays with a ',' and arrays with a ';' - other than a basic understanding that it's related to the dimension and you can TRANSPOSE to swap dimensions )

It's probably worth mentioning that I'm not interested in supplying the (A1:C1) range and having VBA 'manually' sort through each cell and create a two-dimensional array to return.

I explicitly want to apply Excel's CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER function within the workbook to the cell containing the split request - effectively allowing me to use the function on a single cell by pressing ENTER and then a range of cells by pressing CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER.

Hopefully I'm explaining myself well - I'm pretty inexperienced with this stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure this is doable as you want.

Comment: To return into a group of cells usingCtrl-Shift-Enter you will need to loop the range of cells with data and create a 2D array then return that full 2d Array.  It will then fill in the cells up to the cells highlighted.  If you have Office 365 then it will spill automatically without the need of Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: @ScottCraner - OP says "Assuming A1 contains a string that is a path - "C:\Test\Path", an array of strings is returned - {"C","Test","Path"} - and adjacent cells are filled with the text values." To me the "adjacent cells are filled" suggests Office 365 already, but could be wrong.

Comment: I don't think I'm using 365, it's a stand-alone single-user copy. Either way, for whatever reason it seemed intuitive to me that one would be able to write a function that executes in one dimension, and then by using CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER, excel would effectively 'convert' the function and apply it to a 2D or 3D range respectively, dynamically returning 1D arrays when one cell is supplied, or 2D arrays when a row or column is supplied, and then 3D arrays when a range containing rows and columns is supplied. Wishful thinking I suppose

Comment: does the output put the values in 3 cells when doing one cell input without the need of ctrl-shift-enter?

Comment: Yes, it does. Using CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER does not work, atleast properly

Comment: then you most likely have office 365 with the dynamic arrays.  Just build a 2D array and return that.  It will spill the array appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a 2D array and return that:

```
Function SplitPath(rng As Range) As String()
    Dim arr() As String
    ReDim arr(1 To rng.Cells.Count, 1 To 100) As String
    Dim t() As String
    Dim str As String
    Dim j As Long
    j = 1
    Dim k As Long
    Dim mx As Long
    
    
    Dim rngEch As Range
    For Each rngEch In rng
        str = rngEch.Value
        t = Split(str, "\")
        For k = 1 To UBound(t) + 1
           arr(j, k) = t(k - 1)
           If k > mx Then mx = k
        Next k
        j = j + 1
    Next rngEch
    ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr, 1), 1 To mx) As String
    SplitPath = arr
End Function
```

Then depending on the version.

Office 365 put the formula in the upper left of the desired output range and it will spill.

[image]

With older versions, one will need to highlight a range of cells the size of the expected out and put the formula in the formula bar then hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter:

[image]

This function will take a 2D range and return one row per cell:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Scott Craner - your solution does get the job done - albeit I was hoping Excel handled the creation of the multi-dimensional array automatically. 

I assume if I wanted to provide a 2D range to the function (such as cells A1:C2), I would need to modify it further to create and return a 3D array.

Comment: @Skultan172 code does not assume or automatically iterate unless told to.  That is not just vba but any code.

Comment: @Skultan172 and no it would iterate the full range and create a 2D array.  It will go left to right then down a row and left to right.  It will put them all in a nice table with each cell in a new row.

Comment: What is Excels purpose of using CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER in lieu of just ENTER then if not to have the code iterate? I guess my ignorance comes from how Excel handles arrays with it's built-in functions.

Comment: There are two different ways that ctrl-shift-enter was used in older versions.  The first is to highlight a range to return a 2D array.  This method fills the cells with the same formula and links them to return the relative item in the formulas out put of a 2D array.  The second is the use of arrays in the formula to return a single value.  The functions were written in a way to iterate those arrays.  The code behind them did the iteration it did not magically do it.  Someone had to write the code to loop.  Now Ctrl-Shift-Enter is not needed in either case.

Comment: Oh - that's informative - thank you.

Comment: There are many formula that do not allow array entry regardless of using ctrl-shift-enter as the code behind them were not written to iterate or the iteration would impede the normal behavior of the formula.